# Unix Function func_name ### {{{ purpose of #and {

Tags: shell-script, vim

```
Function func_name ### {{{1
{
Function defined 
Return statement 
}    ### }}}1
```

I’m not sure on the purpose of these curly brackets and ###

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Set -A args  - - “$@“ what does this command mean and why do we use - - ?

Comment: Your use of mixed capitalisation is confusing. Capitalisation matters in the shell. Do you mean `set -A` or `set -a`, or some use-defined routine `Set`? In your question, should `Function` actually be `function`? Is the body of the function exactly as you have shown (which would be a syntax error unless `Function` and `Return` are themselves user-defined functions or executables).

Comment: @deepika That question about `$@` is totally unrelated to the vim folds... I suggest you post a separate question about it (or just google it, you'll probably find explanations for both.) Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

These markers `{{{` and `}}}` followed by a number are used to mark the intended fold level when opening this script in the **vim** editor.

See [`:help fold-marker`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/fold.html#fold-marker) for more details. If you open this script in vim for editing,you can see the folding in action by moving the cursor to the line where this function is declared and typing the `za` command, at which point it will fold the function body into a single line. Typing the `za` command again will reopen the fold. (You might need `set foldmethod=marker` for vim to recognize the markers, but it's possible this is already being set for you, maybe through a [modeline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline).)

The markers are typically used inside comments (any comments will do.) I imagine the author decided to use multiple `#`s to make these stand out, perhaps to indicate that they serve a particular purpose. And three is probably to match the number of curly braces used in the vim fold markers.

Comment: Interesting. Is it standard behaviour? +1

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Vim is not a standard editor. Vi does not have folds. So, no.

Comment: @Kusalananda The context is vim; thanks for pointing out the difference. So, is it standard behaviour in vim?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not sure what you mean by "standard" here, folding is a feature of vim and it has commands (such as `za` to "toggle") that "activate" that feature (as in, make it apparent.) The vim help page has more details. There's also `set foldmethod` which can be used to decide how folds are determined, in particular setting it to `marker` will recognize the markers above.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro It's been in Vim since at least 2001.

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger Thanks for the pointers!